# rsync password bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

He creado un script para que se envie las carpetas que se enceuntran en mi servdior a un disco duro.

Lo he hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
     #! /bin/sh
        for i in $(ls)
        do
           time rsync --protect-args -avP $i user@ip:"PATH"
        done
```

Con este trozo de codigo funciona, pero me pide la contraseña por cada una de las carpetas que hay.

Hay alguna manera de automatizarlo?Es decir, poner 1 vez la contraseña y que me funcione?

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer la transferencia sobre ssh con un par de llaves publica/privada? Necesitarías 0 contraseñas...

Answer (score 2):

Para comenzar me tomé la libertad de cambiar el shebang `#!` el cual indica qué intérprete se usarsá para ejecutarlo. Cuando se usa `#!/bin/sh` suele ocurrir que el creador del script asume que el enlace es para un interprete bash, cuando no tiene por qué serlo, y esto suele traer consigo limitaciones.

Luego tengamos en cuenta que la opción `-a` de `rsync` copia los datos de forma recursiva, y además preserva los enlaces simbólicos, los propietarios, los permisos y las fechas de los datos de origen, por lo que no hace falta el uso de un ciclo for para copiar todo lo que almacene un directorio.

Sabido esto podes hacer uso del siguiente script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 4 ]; then
    echo -e "\n MODO DE USO: nombre_de_tu_script <USER> <IP> <SRC_PATH> <DEST_PATH>"
    exit 1
fi

user=$1
ip=$2
src_path=$3
dest_path=$4

time rsync --protect-args -avP $src_path $user@$ip:$dest_path
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos :)